# Running a PHP function in an HTML input tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've looked at other questions about this, but none had an answer for me. I have this line of code:

```
foreach ( $categories as $category ){

echo '<label><input type="checkbox" id="type-'. $category->name . '" value="'. $category->name . '" class="shopping" name="top_level[]"  <?php checked('. $category->name . ', $current)  ?>>'. $category->name . '</label>';
}
```

When I run the file, the correct field shows but has a '>' in front of the text. Firebug shows the HTML output as:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="type-Fashion" value="Fashion" class="shopping" name="top_level[]" <?php="" echo="" checked(fashion,="" $current)="" ?="">
```

Why are there all these `=""` throughout the PHP code?

The `checked()` function is Wordpress and returns the HTML attribute `checked='checked'`, but I believe the problem lies with having PHP in the HTML tag.

The file is saved with .php, I'm running PH P5.5.12 on my WampServer.

I've tried many things, as well as someone else's suggestion:

```
foreach ( $categories as $category ){
?>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="type-<?php echo $category->name; ?> value="<?php echo $category->name; ?>" class="shopping" name="top_level[]"  <?php if(in_array($category->name, $current)){ echo 'checked="checked"';}  ?>><?php echo $category->name; ?> </label>
  <?php  
    }
```

Got this error:

> WARNING: IN_ARRAY() EXPECTS PARAMETER 2 TO BE ARRAY, BOOLEAN GIVEN

`$current` IS an array.

Another post suggested using an equals sign `<?= .....  ?>`. That didn't change anything.

If I remove the PHP code from the input tag, everything works normally.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're obviously wrong about `$current` being an array. Put `var_dump($current)` before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use `<?php` when you're doing literal output (after having used `?>` to get out of script mode), not when you're executing PHP program code. If you're in an `echo` statement, you're executing PHP code. Just concatenate the function call the same way that you concatenate variables.

```
echo '<label><input type="checkbox" id="type-'. $category->name . '" value="'. $category->name . '" class="shopping" name="top_level[]"' . checked($category->name, $current) . '>'. $category->name . '</label>';
```

Comment: might wanna re-think your verbiage here

Comment: @Pamblam Not sure what you mean by that. I added some clarifications.

Comment: In other words, `<?php` takes you out of a plain html context and into a PHP context. But OP was *already* in a PHP context **and** inside a string. So the `<?php` was simply part of the text being echoed out, rather than stepping into a PHP context.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now that it's been pointed out, it makes complete sense, but I'm too new to PHP to have thought to look for it. It worked just fine.

Comment: your first version sorta sounded like "you don't need the opening php tag to execute php code" ..this is betterr

Answer (score 2):

Note the color highlighting above. You're missing a `"`:

```
[..snip..]id="type-<?php echo $category->name; ?> value="<?[..snip..]
                                                 ^---here
```

So the `id` attribute doesn't terminate until AFTER `value=`, leading all of your key=value pairs to be out-of-sync.

What you're seeing is your browser's attempt to clean up the bad HTML you're generating.

Comment: Thanks. This got rid of the error. However, I'm still wondering the original echo statement doesn't parse the php.

Comment: @user1554726 `<?php` isn't parsed inside strings. Everything you echo is simply sent to the browser.